# Sub-domain point to server using WebsitePanel

Tags: websitepanel

Using `WebsitePanel` hosting.

`URL redirection` feature of WebsitePanel redirect `abc.domain1.com` to `xyz.domain2.com`.

What I need to do is browse `abc.domain1.com` and display contents of `xyz.domain2.com` without redirection.

Does it require to update Zone Records or something else ?

Comment: Does this seem sketchy to anyone else?

Comment: Corrected and clarified wording.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! I edited your question as far as I could guess your problem. However, add code and description so that more people with knowledge of the subject will see it. Please edit in the specific error-message you're encountering in case that's necessary to identify the specific problem. Good Luck!

Answer (score 0):

In DNS Zone Records:

1. Added `type = "CNAME"`, `Name = "test"` and `Data = "test.mydomain.com"`.
2. And Edit `type = "A"`    , `Name = ""`     and `Data = "xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx"` (Server IP where it needs to redirect).

This solution is working for me.

Please note that the DNS propagation might take up to 24 hours.